# Caught plagiarizing

Tags: plagiarism

First off, thank you for taking the time to read this and possibly help me.

I'm a freshman in high school. I go to a tech and aggie school so I have a week for academics then it switches off to shop. I have been struggling in my English class. I try very hard, but don't ask for help often. The course is over my head- the pace is far to fast. My teacher is more of a philosopher. He is very intimidating for me, always feeling put on the spot and embarrassed in front of the class. I'm scared to ask for help. His teaching assistant, tries to help me, I guess. She is for certain kids though and cant give me the attention I need. Originally I was put in a high class, but was taken out the next day. To be sadly with the same guy- just his next level down. I still find it over my head. I cannot complete things on time and its beyond stressful.

SO there is this essay due in a very short period of time. I have a hard time reading what we are reading and understanding what is happening. I figured I could copy and paste parts of someone else's off of an answer site, and just change the words. I've done this all the time for other classes, but I always cited my source. But this time was different, I couldn't cite what I was using. I was super stressed out for time and work that I didn't think of it, I copied from the same cite but different answers and tried to combine them while changing some words around. I Handed in the essay only halfway done.. I received a zero and a failing grade in his class. His grades close almost 2 weeks after mine did, so when he put the zero in my grade dropped out of control. I backed myself into a very small corner with dangerous things my way. I'm so scared. My parents and the school admins know. I'm so scared. I'm already getting punished at home, I cant have school do the same. This was a fresh school to a fresh start (Again.. bulling issues and school disabilities).

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because high school is not academia.

Comment: This is a problem that could happen to a graduate student, and the answer would be the same except for dropping the reassurance about the low cost of failing one first year class in high school.

Comment: Agreed, this is off-topic and a duplicate of any number of other questions.  That's not to be a jerk; this is simply not the appropriate forum to help a high-school freshman.  He should be talking to his guidance counselor, teacher, parents and/or principal and not a bunch of strangers on the internet...which is what got him into this mess in the first place.

Comment: _I've done this all the time for other classes_ — I think I know why you're struggling.

Comment: You mentioned bullying and disabilities.  Those are fair topics for questions here....  I suggest that you start to consider your education your own responsibility, and not worry about how your family and your school are going to react to your actions.  Figure out what you are interested in learning more about, and focus on that -- and let everything and everyone else go to hell.  Do not allow yourself to be in a situation where you might feel tempted to cheat -- not because of the prospect of possibly getting in trouble, but because cheating does you no good in the long term.

Comment: Cheating on an assignment means you have nothing invested in it.  If that's the case, then don't turn it in, don't put any effort into it at all.  There's a saying: if something is worth doing, it's worth doing well.  We could also say, if something is not worth doing well, then I guess it wasn't worth doing in the first place.

Comment: Not everyone can benefit from education and you seem to be wasting everyone's time (including your own).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, this is your freshman year of high school. Realize that failing one class your first year is not going to make or break the rest of your time in high school.

Second of all, learn from this experience. It is incredibly easy for a teacher to determine if a student is plagiarizing. Whatever happens next, you should seek guidance on when and how to cite sources. I guarantee you that you are probably unaware of mistakes you have been making.

Finally, you should reach out to this teacher and whoever is disciplining you for your actions. Own up to your mistake without making excuses ("I was rushed", "I was overwhelmed"). Even though these things may be true, focusing on all the reasons why you made your mistake, and how they are not your fault, and how horrible your life will now be, is not going to score you any brownie points. Instead, simply say that you want guidance on how to avoid similar situations in the future. Also discuss options for extra academic support, be this a tutor or finding a different level class to take next year.

You probably can't save your grade, but you can show maturity and be proactive about improving your grades in the future. Good luck!